# how can I cut a line, delete other line and then paste the first one?

Tags: vim

for example, I have the following text:

```
abcdef
ghijkl
...
mnopqr
```

and I want the first line to be put at the end

- I go to the first line, and cut it (shift-V, C)
- I go to the last line and I paste it (p)

it works.

but now, let's say I cut the first line and then I realize I want to delete the line below, then paste the result: when I delete (dd) the line below, it replaces what I cut in the buffer. How can I paste the original line?

Comment: You need to learn about registers. Also, `"_dd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, reading `:help registers` is a must.

In this case I can do `dd dd "2p` However, that works only for string deletions, not for word deletions. So, I think, it's a good habit to always start from copying, like this: `yy 2dd ...more delete commands...  "0p`.